# Azure recovery services not allowing me to select VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to migrate a VM in Southeast Asia to Western Europe

After defining the source in the Enable Replication Section, I am not able to select the virtual machine.

Source Details

[image]

Select Virtual Machine section shows the VM grayed out. 
[image]

My account has Owner, Site Recovery Contributor, Site Recovery Operator, Site Recovery Reader and Virtual Machine Contributor roles.

Comment: Are your Azure VMs using managed disks?

Comment: Yes I am using managed disk.

Comment: Currently, native replication of Azure VMs using managed disks are not supported.You can use "Physical to Azure" option i to migrate VMs with managed disks.More details refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-walkthrough-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, native replication of **Azure VMs using managed disks are not supported**.

You can use "Physical to Azure" option in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-walkthrough-overview) to migrate VMs with managed disks.

More details bout Migrate Azure IaaS virtual machines between Azure regions with Azure Site Recovery , you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-migrate-azure-to-azure#deployment-steps).

Answer (score 0):

Within Azure Site Recovery, are you running an unplanned failover? Per Microsoft's documentation your VM has to meet [these requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/site-recovery-support-matrix-to-azure#failed-over-azure-vm-requirements) to be used. Once you've confirmed that, confirm that you meed the pre-requisites for failover (there is a link at the bottom of the MS requirements document.)

If all those are met, then go to Replicated Items, select your VM, choose the **More** menu, then **Failover**, in the Failover dialog box there is a From box, your VM should be an option in that box. Then follow the steps for a failover per Microsoft.

There are [other sources](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/asr-migration-draas-solution) for using Azure failover that may be informative.